# norm along a dimension is not supported in drake autodiff

Tags: drake

I have the the following line of code which fails:

```
contact_forces = contact_forces / (np.linalg.norm(contact_forces, axis=-1) + 1e-5)[..., np.newaxis]

*** TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type pydrake.symbolic.Variable which has no callable conjugate method
```

Below, I show the various debugging outputs in PDB. Basically the norm fails if you specify the axis argument.

```
(Pdb) contact_forces
array([[[Variable('x(0)', Continuous), Variable('x(1)', Continuous)],
        [Variable('x(2)', Continuous), Variable('x(3)', Continuous)],
        [Variable('x(4)', Continuous), Variable('x(5)', Continuous)]]],
      dtype=object)
(Pdb) np.linalg.norm(contact_forces, axis=-1)
*** TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type pydrake.symbolic.Variable which has no callable conjugate method
(Pdb) np.linalg.norm(contact_forces)
<Expression "sqrt((pow(x(0), 2) + pow(x(1), 2) + pow(x(2), 2) + pow(x(3), 2) + pow(x(4), 2) + pow(x(5), 2)))">
(Pdb) contact_forces.shape
(1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: The issue title is wrong? The operation is not supported is the symbolic::Variable, not AutoDiffXd

Comment: You are computing the contact force in the symbolic form. I wonder why you need to use the symbolic expression. Do you want to eventually evaluate it in double? If so, I would recommend using a matrix of double (or a matrix of autodiffxd if you need the gradient value).